# Convert Array of UnicodeScalar into String in Swift

Tags: swift, string, unicode

I have an array of unicode scalars (Type is `[UnicodeScalar]`)

like:

```
let array = [UnicodeScalar("f")!, UnicodeScalar("o")!, UnicodeScalar("o")!]
```

or

```
let array2 = "bar".unicodeScalars
```

how can I convert efficiently these arrays into a strings again?

Expect:

```
let string1 = ?? // "foo"
let string2 = ?? // "bar"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34294660/2303865

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The second case is simpler because `array2` is a `UnicodeScalarView`
and not an array:

```
let array2 = "bar".unicodeScalars

let str2 = String(array2)
print(str2) // bar
```

If you have an array (or any sequence) of Unicode scalars then you can start with an empty string
and append the elements to its `unicodeScalars` view:

```
let array = [UnicodeScalar("f")!, UnicodeScalar("o")!, UnicodeScalar("o")!]
// Or: let array: [UnicodeScalar] = ["f", "o", "o"]

var str1 = ""
str1.unicodeScalars.append(contentsOf: array)
print(str1) // foo
```

Of course you can define a custom extension for that purpose:

```
extension String {
    init<S: Sequence>(unicodeScalars ucs: S)
        where S.Iterator.Element == UnicodeScalar
    {
        var s = ""
        s.unicodeScalars.append(contentsOf: ucs)
        self = s
    }
}

let str1 = String(unicodeScalars: array)
```

Comment: @LeoDabus: You are right, that is far simpler. You should add an answer ... (with or without extension :)

Comment: I learned that with @dfri so adding it as my answer it is not fair.

Comment: @LeoDabus: I do not see the problem. You have a good solution for this question which should not be hidden in the comments. You can add a reference for proper attribution.

Comment: ok I have posted the comment as an answer with proper attribution

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning (although the `array` example above comes from the OP) that `let array = ["f", "o", "o"].flatMap(UnicodeScalar.init)` could be a "nicer" alternative to initialize `[UnicodeScalar]` examples.

Comment: @dfri: Or (for a literal array): `let array: [UnicodeScalar] = ["f", "o", "o"]`

Comment: That's even better!

Answer (score 7):

You can use this extension from [@dfri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4573247/dfri) to initialize a string from a UnicodeScalar sequence as follow:

```
extension Sequence where Element == UnicodeScalar { 
    var string: String { .init(String.UnicodeScalarView(self)) } 
}
```

---

```
let array: [UnicodeScalar] = ["f", "o", "o"]
print(array.string) //  "foo\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to convert `[UnicodeScalar]` to `String`:

```
let array = [UnicodeScalar("f")!, UnicodeScalar("o")!, UnicodeScalar("o")!]
let string1 = String(array.map{Character($0)})
print(string1 == "foo") //->true
```

Comment: Doesn't this break for characters composed of multiple unicode scalarS?

Comment: @Alexander: No, doesn't. They are combined again when creating the string.

Comment: @MartinR Interesting, I didn't know that

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 5, you can use one of the following ways in order to get a string from a collection of Unicode scalars.

---

### #1. Using `String`'s `init(_:)` initializer

`String` has an [`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1540916-init?changes=latest_major) initializer with the following declaration:

```
init(_ unicodeScalars: String.UnicodeScalarView)
```

> Creates a string corresponding to the given collection of Unicode scalars.

The Playground sample code below shows how to use `init(_:)` in order to get a `String` instance from a `String.UnicodeScalarView` instance:

```
let string = "foo"
let unicodeScalarView = string.unicodeScalars

let newString = String(unicodeScalarView)
print(newString) // prints: foo
```

If you initially have an array of Unicode scalars, you can convert it first to a `String.UnicodeScalarView` instance using `String.UnicodeScalarView`'s [`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/unicodescalarview/2894694-init) initializer:

```
let scalarsArray = [Unicode.Scalar("f"), Unicode.Scalar("o"), Unicode.Scalar("o")]

let unicodeScalarView = String.UnicodeScalarView(scalarsArray)
let newString = String(unicodeScalarView)
print(newString) // prints: foo
```

---

### #2. Using `String`'s `init(_:)` initializer

`String` has an [`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2997126-init) initializer with the following declaration:

```
init(_ scalar: Unicode.Scalar)
```

The following Playground sample codes show how to iterate over an array of Unicode scalars using `String`'s `init(_:)` in order to create a new string:

```
let scalarsArray = [Unicode.Scalar("f"), Unicode.Scalar("o"), Unicode.Scalar("o")]

let string = scalarsArray.reduce("", { partialResult, scalar in
    return partialResult + String(scalar)
})
print(string) // prints: foo
```

```
let scalarsArray = [Unicode.Scalar("f"), Unicode.Scalar("o"), Unicode.Scalar("o")]

let newString = scalarsArray.map(String.init).joined()
print(newString) // prints: foo
```

---

### #3. Using `String.UnicodeScalarView`'s `append(contentsOf:)` method

If you have an existing string and want to append the elements of a Unicode scalars array into it, you can use [`append(contentsOf:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/unicodescalarview/1641591-append):

```
let scalarsArray = [Unicode.Scalar("f"), Unicode.Scalar("o"), Unicode.Scalar("o")]

var newString = ""
newString.unicodeScalars.append(contentsOf: scalarsArray)
print(newString) // prints: foo
```

---

### #4. Using `Character`'s [`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/2906502-init) initializer

Another approach would consist of iterating over a collection of Unicode scalars, convert them into characters (using `Character`'s `init(_:)` initializer) then create a new string from those characters:

```
let scalarsArray = [Unicode.Scalar("f"), Unicode.Scalar("o"), Unicode.Scalar("o")]

let charactersArray = scalarsArray.map(Character.init)
let newString = String(charactersArray)
print(newString) // prints: foo
```